# Conservar links internos al guardar como PDF

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo un archivo excel con enlaces entre varios hojas del mismo excel. Quiero que al guardar en excel como un .pdf (o imprimirlo a un .pdf) me guarde los enlaces entre las hojas.
Por ejemplo: tengo en una hoja excel creado un índice, quiero agregar enlaces a otras partes del libro y me gustaría que al guardar como .pdf se mantuvieran los enlaces internos.
Muchas gracias. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: tengo un enlace en la hoja1 que me lleva a la hoja2. A la hora de imprimir todo el documento en pdf, quiero que me mantenga el hipervínculo entre las hojas.

Comment: Cuando es un vínculo que referencia a una parte interna del documento, creo que no se puede. Solo si son hipervínculos a otras rutas.

Comment: No se puede, ya que al convertirlo a PDF pierde ese esquema al diriges con los vinculos que creaste

Comment: Esta pregunta no trata sobre programación dentro del alcance definido en el centro de ayuda.